# How to merge lists from csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have a few .csv files with words and the frequency of each word in descending order, how could I merge these files into a single .csv?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqyy0.png)

The function I use for the frequency sort is this one:

```
def freq_sort(name):
    with open("CSV_" + str(name[:-4]) + ".csv", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        # next(reader)  # skip first line, if it contains junk
        counter = Counter(chain.from_iterable(takewhile(truth, reader)))
    # print(*counter.most_common())
    print("freq list created")
    writefreq = open("FREQ_" + name, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    for fchar in str(counter.most_common()):
        writefreq.write(fchar)
        if fchar == ')':    # makes it more visual although, not needed. counter.most-common() is the unaltered result
            writefreq.write('\n')
    writefreq.close()
```

It takes a .csv file like this:

[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44T08.png)

Does the frequency sort and creates a .csv with the result.

Example data:

List1:

[('calvià', 1428)
, ('ajuntament', 602)
, ('amb', 79)
, ('mar', 75)
, ('h', 59)
, ('ha', 57)
, ('es', 50)
, ('més', 46)
, ('comunicación', 40)
, ('dia', 35)
, ('avui', 33)
, ('hem', 33)
, ('son', 32)
, ('programa', 32)
, ('jornadas', 32)
, ('santa', 31)
, ('han', 31)
, ('información', 29)
, ('administraciones', 28)
, ('ponça', 27)
, ('fins', 27)
, ('galatzó', 26)
, ('gracias', 25)]

List2:

[('peñíscola', 422)
, ('mar', 74)
, ('ciudad', 51)
, ('feliz', 47)
, ('avui', 34)
, ('noticia', 33)
, ('completa', 33)
, ('semana', 29)
, ('turismo', 27)
, ('gracias', 22)
, ('casco', 22)
, ('antiguo', 22)
, ('castillo', 21)
, ('días', 20)
, ('españa', 20)
, ('imagen', 20)]

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Please provide sample data (not as photo) and your code so far. The code for creating the csv. files is not important

Comment: @Jacob okay sorry, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
list1 =  [('calvià', 1428) , ('ajuntament', 602) , ('amb', 79) , ('mar', 75) , ('h', 59) , ('ha', 57) , ('es', 50) , ('més', 46) , ('comunicación', 40) , ('dia', 35) , ('avui', 33) , ('hem', 33) , ('son', 32) , ('programa', 32) , ('jornadas', 32) , ('santa', 31) , ('han', 31) , ('información', 29) , ('administraciones', 28) , ('ponça', 27) , ('fins', 27) , ('galatzó', 26) , ('gracias', 25)]

list2 = [('peñíscola', 422) , ('mar', 74) , ('ciudad', 51) , ('feliz', 47) , ('avui', 34) , ('noticia', 33) , ('completa', 33) , ('semana', 29) , ('turismo', 27) , ('gracias', 22) , ('casco', 22) , ('antiguo', 22) , ('castillo', 21) , ('días', 20) , ('españa', 20) , ('imagen', 20)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns =['word', 'frequency'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2, columns =['word', 'frequency'])


result =  pd.concat( [df1, df2])
result.to_csv("example.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to modify your df in order of frequency you can do this.
Few Links for your reference.
[Group By](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) , [Value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('Column Name')['Column Name'].transform(pd.Series.value_counts)
df.sort_values('count', ascending=False)
```

If you want to merge the files then you can use following script

keep all the files into same directory and you can merge them directly.
If folder contains multiple files with other extension just use wildcard entry. "*.csv" after directory.
[Reference URL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-merge-all-csv-files-into-a-single-dataframe-python-pandas#:%7E:text=To%20merge%20all%20CSV%20files%2C%20use%20the%20GLOB%20module.,merge%20the%20CSV%20files%20together.)

```
import glob
import os
files = os.path.join("file_directory\", "newmergedFileName*.csv")
files = glob.glob(files)
```